# Safe cross-compiler ABI in C++?

Tags: c++

In the cpp core guidelines, there is a (partially incomplete) [statement](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-abi):

> I.26: If you want a cross-compiler ABI, use a C-style subset
>
> Reason
>
> Different compilers implement different binary layouts for classes, exception handling, function names, and other implementation details.
>
> Exception
>
> You can carefully craft an interface using a few carefully selected higher-level C++ types. See ???.

A good example of a cross-compiler ABI would be a plugin system. Let's say I want this to be as C++-friendly as possible.

The interface:

```
class Plugin
{
public:
    virtual ~Plugin() {}

    enum class Type {A, B, C};
    virtual Plugin::Type getType() const = 0;

    virtual void doWork() = 0;
};

// C-style for the main plugin entry function
typedef Plugin* (*PluginCreateCallback)();
typedef void (*PluginDestroyCallback)(Plugin*);
extern "C" void pluginMain(PluginCreateCallback* createCb, PluginDestroyCallback* destroyCb);
```

A plugin implementation (compiled with compiler#1) might look like:

```
class MyPlugin: public Plugin
{
    Plugin::Type getType() const override {return Plugin::Type::A;}
    void doWork() {...}
};

Plugin* myCreateCb()
{
    return new MyPlugin();
}

void myDestroyCb(Plugin* plugin)
{
    delete plugin;
}

extern "C" void pluginMain(PluginCreateCallback* createCb, PluginDestroyCallback* destroyCb)
{
    *createCb = &myCreateCb;
    *destroyCb = &myDestroyCb;
}
```

The application implementation (compiled with compiler#2) would contain something like:

```
handle->pluginMain(&createCb, &destroyCb);
Plugin* plugin = createCb();
plugin->doWork();
destroyCb(plugin);
```

**Questions**:

- is it safe to use classes like `Plugin` in a cross-compiler environment? (will it be represented the same in memory?)
- will extending the `Plugin::Type` enum affect how the Plugin class is represented?
- more generally, what would be those "carefully selected higher-level C++ types"?

**Update**:

In the "API design for C++" book by Martin Reddy, chapter 12, the exact scenario of using plugin interfaces seems to be specified:

> Implementing virtual methods of an abstract base class can insulate
>   a plugin from ABI problems because a virtual method call is usually represented as an index into
>   a class’s vtable. Theoretically, the vtable format can differ between compilers, but in practice this
>   tends not to happen.

From this, I understand that using abstract classes is generally safe between compilers, but definitely not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: "Different compilers implement different ... function names" - unless the two compilers exactly agree on [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) rules, `plugin->doWork();` in your example will go splat. (wikipedia quote: "The C++ language does not define a standard decoration scheme, so each compiler uses its own.") So in theory the answer is no. Do you have some real-life platforms on mind? Some may have cross-compiler ABIs agreed for multiple compilers.

Comment: @jakub_d Yes, that may be the case. For platforms, I would say Windows, Linux, and Mac (for which MSVC, gcc/mingw, and clang I think share the biggest part of the compiler market). But I would keep the question platform-agnostic.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1438#issuecomment-504137513 after seeing this question asking for relevant exceptions and the answer seems to be that there are no such exceptions, and this paragraph will be removed.

Comment: @Holt Great, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1438) to get examples of such exceptions and [Herb Sutter's answer](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1438#issuecomment-504137513) was:

> Editors call: We don't have a reference to point to, so we agree we should just remove the Exception. Thanks!

This *Exception* paragraph [has now been removed](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/commit/a255fe23e0f6ad07d419b35851eec7b4af6a92fd) from the guildelines.